# Symfony2, dql is not working with REPEAT function

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

```
public function mpttLocationList() {
        $q = $this->_em->createQuery("
        SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('.', COUNT(parent.region_name) - 1), node.region_name) AS name
        FROM ViveListingBundle:region_redefine AS node,
                ViveListingBundle:region_redefine AS parent
        WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        GROUP BY node.region_name
        ORDER BY node.lft");
        return $q->getResult();
    }
```

The above code is giving the error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 23: Error: Expected known function, got 'REPEAT'.
```

Comment: How is that question related to Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

`REPEAT` is not a valid DQL function. Remeber that DQL is not SQL, it looks similar but it has important differences and does not support all the SQL constructs. Take a look at the DQL documentation to see what is supported:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Answer (score 0):

To teach Doctrine about `REPEAT()`, you need to [define a custom DQL function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) and [register it with Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html).